# How can I do tree_method ='exact' in XGBoost classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost, ensemble-modeling

I am doing XGBoost classification on a huge data set and its showing:

`Tree method is automatically selected to be 'approx' for faster speed. to use old behavior(exact greedy algorithm on single machine), set tree_method to 'exact'`

How can I shift it to be exact?

I have tried `clf = xgb(tree_method='exact')` and it returned error!

Comment: Why do you want to change it? It shouldn't change the output of your model. If you are concerned about speed, there are other things you should worry about first.

Comment: @jeweinb What do you mean there are other things to worry about?  XGBoost now has GPU support which can immensely speed up your training time.  Really stupid comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `tree_method` is a parameter for Tree Booster. There are 4 choices, namely, `auto`, `exact`, `approx` and `hist`. The default is set to `auto` which  heuristically chooses a faster algorithm based on the size of your dataset. Approximate algorithm (`approx`) is chosen in your case since your dataset is huge.

To change the tree construction algorithm, you have to pass `tree_method` in the `train` function as follows:

```
import xgboost as xgb
...
parameters = {'tree_method': 'exact'} #You can add other parameters as well
model = xgb.train(parameters, x_train, num_round) #num_round is the number of rounds for boosting
prediction = model.predict(x_test)
...
```

I hope this helps.